# Set store value using REDUX

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a process in redux that retrieves a Session ID from a REST API auth call, and I am trying to wrap my mind around how I can set a store value once I am able to retrieve that Session ID.

I understand the basics of REDUX in REACT and can do simple things like toggle true/false and so on. I am just having a learning curve issue passing values into REDUX.

This is my main process that goes out and grabs a session ID which is ultimately stored in data.

GrabSession.js

```js
import React from "react";
import base64 from 'react-native-base64';
import settings from '../../settings.json';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {createSession} from './action';

class FetchSession extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {

    const url = settings.server_URI + "auth";
    let username = settings.user;
    let password = settings.password;
    let headers = new Headers();
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));

    const response = await fetch(url,{method:'GET',
        headers: headers,

       });
    const data = await response.text();;
    console.log(data)

  }

  render()
    {

    return (
      <React.Fragment/>
   );
 }

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    createSession: (value) => dispatch({
        type: 'setSession',
        Session: value })
  }
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(FetchSession)
```

This is my reducer

```js
const initialState = {
  Session: null,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "setSession":
      return {
        ...state,
        Session: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is my action.js

```js
export const createSession = (Session) => {
  return {
    type: 'setSession',
    Session: Session
  }
}
```

My goal would be to have a SessionID in the REDUX store with the actual session ID retrieved from GrabSession.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside GrabSession.js add these lines.

```
const { createSession } = this.props;
....
....
const { session } = data;
createSession(data);
```

Change mapDispatchToProps function to

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  createSession: (session) => dispatch(createSession(session)),
})
```

Also need to change this line `export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(FetchSession)` to 
`export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FetchSession)`.

update createSession in action.js to

```
export const createSession = (Session) => ({
  type: 'setSession',
  payload: Session,
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Daniel.